# Programmatically changing UIButton font color depending on state

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I'm trying to programmatically create a UIButton. However by default it's turning up white (which is the default color for my navigation bar, I feel that's relevant). I want it to just be Apple's default blue color in iOS7. I've managed to change the color for it's default state, but the moment I select it the text becomes white again. I cannot figure out how to keep it blue.

Could someone please explain to me how I can programmatically create a UIButton and have it act the same as though I created it in storyboard?

Current code:

```
UIButton *cancelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake(320 - 150, 0, 140, 40);
[cancelButton setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
cancelButton.titleLabel.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:122.0/255.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
cancelButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:122.0/255.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Thank you.

Comment: Setting the titleLabel has never worked for me. @SunnyShah is the way to go.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this code :

```
UIButton *cancelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[cancelButton setFrame:CGRectMake(320 - 150, 0, 140, 40)];
[cancelButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[cancelButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cancelButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted]; // This will helps you during click time title color will be blue color
[cancelButton setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(button_Action) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:cancelButton];
```

Comment: Although you weren't the first to answer, this is the most detailed. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Just tried with

```
[cancelButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:122.0/255.0 blue:1.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

For more information read [official documentation of `UIButton`.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html)

Comment: The blue should be -> blue:1.0f and not blue:1.0/255.o

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this

```
[cancelButton setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cancelButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem,

```
    [cancelButton setTitleColor:YOUR COLOR forState:SPECIFIED STATE];
```

The state values are :

```
UIControlStateNormal
UIControlStateHighlighted                
UIControlStateDisabled    
UIControlStateSelected
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`- (void)setTitleColor:(UIColor *)color forState:(UIControlState)state`

for specifying colors for all the required states.

Comment: I see. That worked. I thought titleLabel would encompass all of them, clearly I was wrong. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. The reason why `titleLabel` doesn't work for this is that it actually references just the current title property of the `UIButton` (not titles for all states), like the documentation specifies: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/titleLabel.

Answer (score 0):

Swift:

```
let button = UIButton (type: UIButtonType.system)
```

This will create a button that uses the standard tint color just like a button added to a storyboard in interface builder.